# Microsoft Exam: Storing global information in mvc application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web

I´ve been training for a Microsoft Exam and I found that this question has an answer which I don't think it is right.

Question: **You are designing a distributed application. The application must store a small amount of insecure global information that does not change frequently.**

- A. Application state
- B. Session state
- C. Database support
- D. Profile properties

According to the PDF, the right answer should be **A,B**. But I think that since the application must store **global** information then the right answer should be **A,C**. Session state is valid just for one user, so it does not make sense to store global information on it.

What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The A,B answers request minimum of code and overhead**, also can be a lot faster to store a small amount of global data, so you can prefer them

vs **the C,D** that is stored in a database and you **need a lot more over all code to handle them**.

A,B can be a a static variable in (A) case, or a generic List in case B.
C,D, require setup of the database, or setup of properties, and code to access, read, write, delete and all that, to the database.

In any case this can be a primary opinion answer, because if you have all ready setup your database and you have a good DAL layer, you can go with database too. From the other hand is faster to access data that are not use database...

Comment: I agree with you... but I think that if you store global information in a Session then you won´t be able to use this data outside that session, will you?

Comment: @LuisTeijon No will you not - also you also will not see them in static variables if you use web garden. Global Unique Data  you can have only with database. This is something that I am not sure that is clarified, what global data means, global for the user, global for all users... global that changes or global that needed for cache

Comment: do you meant web farm?

Comment: @LuisTeijon and web farm and web garden. Static is the same only one each process... every process in the pool have different static variables.